# How could I style a slider created through the createButton function in p5.js using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, button, styles, p5.js

I have to use p5.js and I cannot use CSS for this particular project. Since createButton yields a p5.element, I did use .style, but I cannot make any attributes past the 'width' to work. Below are the equivalent CSS properties which I would like to integrate. Could you help me with at least two of the below styles as an example?

```
width: 100 % ; /* Full-width */
height: 25 px; /* Specified height */
background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
outline: none; /* Remove outline */
opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */ -
webkit - transition: .2 s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
transition: opacity .2 s;
```

Answer (score 0):

The style of a button ([`createButton()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createButton)) or slider ([`createSlider()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createSlider)) can be changed by `.style(name, value)`. e.g.:

```js
button = createButton("my button");
button.style("height", "25 px");
button.style("background", "#d3d3d3");
// [...]
```